# Partial String matching in two large strings

Tags: string, design-patterns, matching

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find out all partial matches in 2 large strings. For example,

```
string 1: "Thisismyfirststring"
string 2: "searchismyfirtestring"
```

This should return "his", "hisismyfir", "string", etc.

Is this possible?

Regards..

Comment: Take some time, format your question and make it readable. At the moment i am not able to get what you want. Also make sure you attach relevant code which you think works/not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a boolean matrix M where M(i,j) tells you if the i'th character of one string matches the j'th character of the other. A matching substring will now be a diagonal line of `true` in M, so now walk the matrix and look for those.

Comment: Thanks Joni. Can you please elaborate a bit? Else do we have any sort of efficient built-in packages, because I am looking at strings which are at least 3000 characters in length and matches can happen for around 300-400 characters.

Comment: What I have described is essentially the dynamic programming algorithm for [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), which you can easily adapt to your purposes. Strings of 3000 by 3000 characters lead to a boolean matrix of only 10MB, so that's not a big problem. If this is for protein or DNA sequencing, yes, there are efficient packages.